# Does deepstream clients unsubscribe when disconnecting?

Tags: deepstream.io

From the docs:

> The listen-callback is called with isSubscribed = true once a matching
>   event is subscribed to for the first time and with isSubscribed =
>   false once the last subscriber for a matching event unsubscribes.

If a browser client disconnects abruptly, will deepstream automatically unsubscribe it subscriptions eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it will. Loosing a connection will automatically remove all subscriptions for that connection on the server side and also notify the listening mechanism in the process.

In fact, even when a client just disconnects temporarily during a connection loss, all its subscriptions will be removed and re-established once it reconnects.